# Stop rendering session during breaks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I'm trying to make a Pomodoro timer and I'm almost done but I've been stuck on one thing for so long. I am trying to make it so that after every session and break, the session increases by 1 instead of by 2. I've made a bandaid by saying increase by .5 but I want to fix it with some kind of logic

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Pomodoro() {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(25);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [displayMessage, setDisplayMessage] = useState(false);
  const [session, setSession] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      clearInterval(interval);

      

      if (seconds === 0 && minutes !== 0) {
        setSeconds(59);
        setMinutes(minutes - 1);
      } else if (seconds === 0 && minutes === 0) {
        let breakTime = session % 4 === 0 ? 14 : 4;
        let minutes = displayMessage ? 24 : breakTime;
        let seconds = 59;


        if (displayMessage) setSession(prev => prev + .5);
        
        setSeconds(seconds);
        setMinutes(minutes);
        setDisplayMessage(!displayMessage);
      } else {
        setSeconds(seconds - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, [seconds, displayMessage, minutes, session,]);

  const timerMinutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
  const timerSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
  return (
    <div className="pomodoro">
      <div> Session: {session} </div>
      <div className="message">
        {displayMessage && <div>Break time! New Session starts in:</div>}
      </div>
      <div className="timer">
        {timerMinutes}:{timerSeconds}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pomodoro;
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain how your code is meant to work?

Comment: Yes, it's a Pomodoro timer, each time a session (25 minutes) ends, a break starts (5 minutes) and after 4 sessions, a 15-minute break starts. After the 15 minute break, a new session with 4 counts starts.  The code is working with a bandaid... instead of using .5 I would like to increase the session by 1, but If you use 1, the session increases by 2 after each break. So the code thinks that each break is a session..